# Get an email when a script finishes running in Matlab -nojvm

Tags: java, matlab, email

I am running Matlab without the Java graphical interface (`matlab -nojvm`) and I would like to get an email when a script finished running (I am running tons).

I tried using `sendmail` and [matlabmail](https://gist.github.com/dgleich/9243281) but both require Java. I also tried using the Linux command `mail` but it doesn't work. Do you have any tips on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Look at this post for insight.  Using `mail/mailx` may not work because if you're using an internet connection provided by an ISP, they most likely require that you authenticate with a mail server before sending email.  You need to do some set up before you can get your terminal to send out email.  http://superuser.com/questions/408335/mailx-is-not-sending-any-mail

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the graphical window without loosing java functionality by using `matlab -nodisplay`. This way, sendmail still works in my case.